# A simple question about limits.

Tags: limits, exponential-function, infinity

This may seem like a simple question, but I feel as if it is wrong but I am unsure why. 
Is it possible to evaluate a limit in two stages for example:
say you know that $x(1- a)\rightarrow b$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$, would I be correct in saying

$(1 - \frac{x(1 - a)}{x})^x \rightarrow (1 - \frac{b}{x})^x \rightarrow \exp(-b)$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not correct in general to do a "2-stage-limit" as you suggest. Otherwise, you could argue that for instance $$\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x \xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{} 1$$
"since" $1+\frac{1}{x} \xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{} 1$ and $1^x \xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{} 1$.

it might still yield the right result in some cases, but the derivation cannot be argued that way -- you need to get your hands a bit dirtier.

Comment: Could I just imply that $(1 - \frac{x(1 - a)}{x})^x \rightarrow  \exp(-b)$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$ instead.

Comment: @user200632 Just rewrite $$(1-\frac{x(1-a)}{x})^x = e^{x\ln(1-\frac{x(1-a)}{x}) }= e^{x\ln(1-\frac{b+o(1)}{x})}$$ for instance, and use Taylor expansions -- you will get the result.